# Replacement body-pack transmitter for Shure UT1 / UT4A

Tags: live, hardware

We have a very nice Shure UT4A wireless diversity receiver (UHF, 615.9 Mhz) that we use with a UT1 body-pack transmitter.  Unfortunately, the transmitter seems to be failing as it has been increasingly losing connection to the receiver (both sides!) during live use, causing very bad "pops" as it loses, then regains connection.

Now obviously, I am hoping that the problem is the UT1 transmitter ($200) rather than the UT4A receiver ($400), but I am not sure how to check.

Worse, the UT1 appears to be obsolete, but I do not know what replacements for it I could buy that will work with the UT4A diversity receiver.

Any help would be *much* appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the cable to the microphone? The cable could be broken on the inside, making large pops when there's a short circuit.

Comment: It's definitely the transmission, not the mic, etc.

Comment: For migration to SD please Tim

Comment: @DrMayhem This is a question about the hardware being used in on-location music recording.  Is that not on-topic here?  It appears to be from my reading of the help center article linked below.

Comment: All audio questions are being migrated as part of the AVP part merge with Sound Design. So yes, it was on topic here, but that part is moving :-)

Comment: @RBarryYoung - which, by the way, if you haven't already, you'll want to make a profile on Sound Design so that you'll properly get credit and notifications and such about your questions after migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only bodypack transmitter that worked with the UT4 receiver is the UT1. So, you would need to find a used UT1 on the exact frequency as your receiver.

Also, there is a place in Chicago that repairs older Shure wireless systems. Contact Delta Audio ([www.deltaaudio.biz](http://www.deltaaudio.biz))